# Difference between ByteArray and Array<Byte> in kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I don't understand why e.g. the `java.security.MessageDigest.digest()` method which is declared as returning `byte[]` in Java returns a `ByteArray` in Kotlin although Kotlin usually seems to call `byte[]` an `Array<Byte>`.

E.g. the following does not work:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
  if (md == null) throw NullPointerException()
  val result : Array<Byte>? = md.digest() 
}
```

Type mismatch: inferred type is `ByteArray?` but `Array<Byte>?` was expected

Comment: Current docs for Kotlin arrays: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays and for interop with Java arrays from Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-arrays

Answer (score 52):

Due to Java's limitations, Kotlin has 9 array types: Array<...> for arrays of references (in the JVM sense) and 8 specialized array types, i.e. IntArray, ByteArray etc.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-arrays

The main reason for this distinction is performance: if we didn't specialize arrays it'd lead to a lot of boxing/unboxing and make arrays slow. This would be unacceptable because the only reason one might want to prefer arrays over collections is **performance**.

Answer (score 33):

Said in short, just for future reference.

> **ByteArray** equals **byte[]** in Java
>   **Array<Byte>** equals **Byte[]** in Java

No benefit from using one over the other in Kotlin, only if the code is to be parsed to Java.

Comment: There is a benefit to using ByteArray, each entry is a primitive, so the ByteArray requires less memory and potentially saves some auto-boxing.

Comment: Simple and clear answer. as I know, java developers use byte[] rather than Byte[].